# 3d Trapz (or Simps) like Matlab

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I have a 3D array that I need to integrate numerically using Python.  My array is a function of wavelength, depth and time. It is data that I have modelled numerically using another software package and don't have an analytical form of the function, just the 3d array output from the other package.  I need to find the triple integral of this array.  In Matlab I use trapz(my_array, 3)  where 3 is the ndims to integrate over.  The Scipy trapz only seems to work on a single integral.

I think I may have 2 options but I am I need some advice.

opt 1. use 3d interpolation in scipy that returns a function handle, do these exist? the 1d version returns a function, and then use scipy.integrate.tplquad to do the integration over the interpolated function where I use the max and in values in my array as the integration limits.

opt 2. use three nested trapz calls like this suggestion for 2d I found on another site. --> sp.trapz(sp.trapz(f, y[np.newaxis,:], axis=1), x, axis=0))

Can't quite get my head around to make either work.  Any help/advice would be appreciated.  I need to make sure that my integration error is as low as possible.

Comment: This certainly depends on how the 3D array and the mathematical function relate. Imagine the question being asked for a 1D array. We couldn't really tell you what the *integral of a 1D array* is either.
It's quite likely you want one of these: You want to integrate a piecewise constant function [1D: something like a histogram], the implementation of which is simply: `np.sum(F)*dx*dy*dz`.[`dx`,`dy`,`dz` being the stepwidths between each value] Or: You want to integrate some  interpolant of your data [as in trapezoidal rule for 1D piecewise linear interpolation].